# How to manage Core Data to fulfill appropriate section?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I have one Table View Controller (CardTableViewController) with three sections (English, Chinese, Spanish) and another View Controller (CardEditViewController) where i can add new items in cards: e.g. i can add "Lesson 6" to English.
The problem is that i use Core Data, but when i create a new item, it appears not only in English but elsewhere (in English, Spanish and Chinese – the same item everywhere).

How can i create it to save only in the appropriate section? It's some kind of relationship.

**CardTableViewController.m**

```
#import "CardTableViewController.h"
@import CoreData;

@interface CardTableViewController ()

@property (strong) NSMutableArray *collections;

@end

@implementation CardTableViewController

- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext
{
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = nil;
    id delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    if ([delegate performSelector:@selector(managedObjectContext)]) {
        context = [delegate managedObjectContext];
    }
    return context;
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];


    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [self managedObjectContext];
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Collection"];
    self.collections = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil] mutableCopy];

    [self.tableView reloadData];
}



- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return self.collections.count;
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSManagedObject *collection = [self.collections objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [cell.textLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [collection valueForKey:@"name"]]];



    return cell;
}



- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    return YES;
}


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {

        [context deleteObject:[self.collections objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

        NSError *error = nil;
        if (![context save:&error]) {
            NSLog(@"Can't Delete! %@ %@", error, [error localizedDescription]);
            return;
        }

        [self.collections removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }
}

@end
```

**CardEditViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface CardEditViewController : UIViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *nameCommon;

- (IBAction)save:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)cancel:(id)sender;

@end
```

**CardEditViewController.m**

```
#import "CardEditViewController.h"
@import CoreData;

@interface CardEditViewController ()



@end

@implementation CardEditViewController

- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext {
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = nil;
    id delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    if ([delegate performSelector:@selector(managedObjectContext)]) {
        context = [delegate managedObjectContext];
    }
    return context;
}

- (IBAction)cancel:(id)sender {
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}

- (IBAction)save:(id)sender {
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];


    NSManagedObject *newCollection = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Collection" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [newCollection setValue:self.nameCommon.text forKey:@"name"];


    NSError *error = nil;

    if (![context save:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Can't Save! %@ %@", error, [error localizedDescription]);
    }

    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}


@end
```

Comment: If we can't see your dataModel, or a least your NSManagedObject. It´ll be difficult to help you.

Comment: paste some code here what u are trying

Comment: Please show how your `Collection` entity looks like. Also, when including code in your question, please remove commented-out code and auto-generated methods (like `viewDidLoad`), which only call `super` implementation. You will get much better answers if you provide a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: my Collection entity contains just one attribute name, type: String

Answer (score 0):

This not how it is done. You are trying to solve problems that have already been solved for you. Instead, you should use a `NSFetchedResultsController` to populate a table view with Core Data.

Create a new project (e.g. Master-Detail) and check the "Core Data" option to see how this is done. You can copy paste the fetched results controller code into your app without many modifications.